# I cannot install eclipse jaxb builder plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jaxb

I am currently working with a product that is built onto Eclipse version 3.4.2.

I am trying to install the [jaxb builder](http://www.viewstreet.com/joomla/index.php?option=com_newsfeeds&view=category&id=39&Itemid=80) plugin, but it is not working.

So far I have tried:

- Unzipping the folder into the Eclipse plugins folder and then restarting Eclipse
- The restarting Eclipse using the -clean flag
- Unzipping the folder into the product's (built onto Eclipse) plugin folder and then restarting with and without -clean
- Unzipping the folder into the dropins folder and then restarting Eclipse

I think that it may be possible that this version of jaxb builder doesn't support my version of Eclipse, but I can't figure out how to find that information. I tried emailing the address on the "Contact Us" page, but it came right back to me.

Is it possible that the product has been discontinued? How can I find out?

Answer (score 0):

Discontinued? I don't know but the last build is from 2011-05. It's built against Eclipse 3.4 (see plugin.xml). What do you mean be "not working"? Exceptions? Entries in Eclipse error log/view?

Comment: Nothing. There are no exceptions that I can see. No entries in the Problems tab (if that's what you're referring to). It just doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was the application's fault. I'm not exactly sure what the problem was, but when I did the exact same thing in a regular Eclipse environment, it came up with no issues.

I will edit if I get more information.